# Django standalone script : need to import django.db to see logging

Tags: python, django

I found a very strange behaviour with django standalone script :
When I want to print some debug information with python loggin service,
I must import django.db to see them : Why ?

I am using Django 1.4.5

Here is the test case :

I create a blank projet :

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I Define logging parameters into settings.py :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)-8s : %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'mysite': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

And write the standalone script in the same directory as settings.py:

script.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mysite')

#import django.db

logger.debug('hello logging !')
```

when import django.db is not present :

```
(no output)
```

when import django.db is present :

```
'DEBUG    : hello logging !' is printed on console
```

Is it possible to see debug informations without importing django.db that I do not need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing standalone script you should to write [django custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/).

Answering your question this behavior is achieved by accessing `django.conf.settings` attribute in [`django.db`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.5/django/db/__init__.py#L11) module.

Django settings is lazy object. Once any of settings property requested, lazy settings object initialize settings object and perform configuration of logging.

Look at chain of methods in [LazySettings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.4/django/conf/__init__.py#L24):

1. `__getattr__` call `_setup`
2. `_setup` call `_configure_logging`